# Setting the URL text for a CMFCLinkCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, hyperlink, mfc

If I create a `CMFCLinkCtrl` control programmatically and assign the text in the constructor all is well. But if I then try to change the URL to something else it does not update visually. According to the documentation for [`SetURL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfclinkctrl-class?view=msvc-170#seturl) it states:

> Displays a specified URL as the button text.

But when you look at the underlying MFC source for the control all it does is:

```
void CMFCLinkCtrl::SetURL(LPCTSTR lpszURL)
{
    if (lpszURL == NULL)
    {
        m_strURL.Empty();
    }
    else
    {
        m_strURL = lpszURL;
    }
}
```

Calling `UpdateWindow();` or `Invalidate();` on the control made no difference. I then realised that the IDE has **two** properties:

[image]

For **Caption** is states:

> Specifies the text displayed by the control.

For **URL** it states:

> Specifies the url string of the link control.

In the end I simply did this:

```
m_linkStatusbarLocalCong.SetURL(strCongregation);
m_linkStatusbarLocalCong.SetWindowText(strCongregation);
```

Now it is working fine. Did I miss something in reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I miss something in reading the documentation?

No. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfclinkctrl-class#seturl) clearly states:

> ```cpp
> void SetURL(LPCTSTR lpszURL);
> ```
>
> *`lpszURL`*
> [in] The button text to display.

And that is a lie. `SetURL()` updates the protected class member `m_strURL` only but doesn't perform any additional steps. If everything else in the implementation was sane this wouldn't be a big deal, and calling `UpdateWindow()` would reconcile the visual representation with the internal state.

Albeit, *nothing* in `CMFCLinkCtrl`'s implementation is sane. The code in `OnDraw()` reaches out and reads the window text for display and never even considers `m_strPrefix`/`m_strURL`.

In essence, `SetWindowText()` controls what's being displayed, and `SetURLPrefix()`/`SetURL()` sets the URL to be launched on click. You have to update both so that the display is consistent with the behavior.

I don't know why MFC chose to roll their own `CMFCLinkCtrl` instead of wrapping a native [SysLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-syslink-syslink-control-overviews) control. I do know that it was executed incredibly sloppily.